# Installation from shared drive

Tags: virtual-machine, network-shares, remote-access, remote-control

I want to install a software from a shared drive in a Virtual Machine from the base machine.Is there any way to disable open file security warning using command prompt

Answer (score 1):

Open the Internet Explorer settings.

In the `Security` tab, you'll find `Local Intranet`.

Click the `Sites` button and check `automatically detect intranet network`.

If that doesn't work, you can just add the IP of the base machine to your `Trusted Sites` zone.

Comment: i have already mentioned in the question using command line....

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a backup as this will trounce on file metadata.
2. Unblock the files by removing metadata

   a. [streams.exe](http://SysInternals.com/) -d -s Z:\
3. Change Integrity

   b. [icacls.exe](http://YourWindowsMachine.me/Windows/System32/icacls.exe/) Z:\ /SetIntegrityLevel (CI)(OI)M